# 6 Districts and 6 Robberies

Tags: probability

The question - *A city with 6 districts has 6 robberies in a particular week. Assume the robberies are located randomly, with all possibilities for which robbery occurred where equally likely. What is the probability that some district had more than 1 robbery?*

Solution says there are 6^6 possible configuration for which robbery occurred where (i.e. the denominator). I got stuck when I thought each district could have had 0 robbery or 1 or 2 ... 6 robberies. District A having more than one robberies would imply some other district having zero robbery. How do you arrive at the figure of 6^6 then?

Solution also says the problem is identical to throwing a die 6 times and finding the probability of having a different face show up each time. But again, the probability of a face showing up in one throw is independent of the face which showed up on the previous throw, but in the case of a district, a robbery happening in the first district would imply none of the other cities could have 6 robberies since the total is fixed unlike in the case of the die.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the meaning of the $6^6$ term. Imagine ordering the location of the robberies by the time they occurred. One possible list of districts is "A, A, B, D, A, E." Another is "E, A, B, D, C." There are $6^6$ possible outcomes since there are six possible districts for the first robbery, six districts for the second robbery, and so on.

For the numerator, you want to count sequences where each district appears exactly once, such as "E, A, B, D, C."

Comment: Thanks for your response.

But one thing still confuses me, this particular explanation talks about arranging robberies among the location, but what if we look from the perspective of location first. I guess this is where my misunderstanding comes up. 

When I talk about arranging robberies among the districts, it makes sense as you explained. But what if I want to go to location first and arrange robberies among them, like allocating 7 options (6 robberies or nothing) to district 1 and so on. Can you direct me what specifically I am thinking wrong here.

Comment: @RitvikSharma your approach is not wrong, it is just a more cumbersome approach since allocating some number of robberies to district A will affect how many robberies appears in other districts, which will devolve into a lot of casework. Even if you do pursue this approach, you will end up doing what is described above anyway, since the probability model is *the location of each robbery is random*; it is best to work directly with how the probability model is set up.

Comment: I am aligned with you on this. I tried to read a bit more about my approach and found it will be solved using the sum of multinomial coefficients. Which in turn does what is done above. But thanks again for the point "it is best to work directly with how the probability model is set up"

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the same as the birthday problem.  But instead of determining the probability that 2 kids have the same birthday you're determining the inverse -- that no 2 robberies occur in the same district.

You could do it easily by computing the likely hood that no district had 2 robbers.  And then subtract from 1.

1st robber can pick any district (probability = 1 = 6/6).
2nd robber must pick one of the remaining 5 districts (5/6).
3rd robber must pick one of the remaining 4 districts (4/6).
4th robber (3/6).
5th robber (2/6).
6th robber (1/6).

So the answer is:
$$1- \frac{6!}{6^6} = 0.0154$$